# Array elements into sub-arrays?

Tags: javascript

My question is the following: How to group array elements into sub-arrays inside the same array with javascript?

**Example**: `[ 11, 5, 13, 10, 23, 25, 7, 6 ]`

The result I want to achieve: `[ [11, 5], [13, 10], [23, 25], [7, 6] ]`

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: _"tried some code"_, so show us what you tried...

Comment: Note that the only thing flag-worthy in this comment chain was that comment of yours, Mbk.

Comment: @MbkHamza : cerbrus is totaly right, it's clear that you don't know how the site is working and how to ask question. Stackoverflow is not a coding service : we don't ask people to write code for us. We ask people to help us find solution to a code you wrote by yourself

Comment: @MbkHamza you are "new" and that's why you are getting all these comments. We are not agressive with you BUT we are helping you. he have the responsabiliy to keep this website with a high quality content. When you will earn more reputation it will also be your responsibility to help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate through the array and find the index by using `index/2`.
Then create an array or push the `index` element into the array.
Below is the full code.

```js
var arr = [ 11, 5, 13, 10, 23, 25, 7, 6 ];

let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  let index = Math.floor(i/2);
  let a = acc[index] || [];
  a.push(curr);
  acc[index] = a;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: The third parameter passed to the `reduce` callback is `currentIndex`. Use that.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're getting answers now, at least let's simplify the method:

```js
var arr = [ 11, 5, 13, 10, 23, 25, 7, 6 ];

let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, n, i) => {
  i = Math.floor(i/2);   // Calculate the proper index
  acc[i] = acc[i] || []; // Make sure acc[i] is an array
  acc[i].push(n);        // Add the current value to the array.
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```